# Is there a easy way to profile a java program in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I prefer to use eclipse to develop but have been unable to figure out how to profile in it.  I read that I need to open the profiling perspective but the options aren't there when I look(the [documentation on eclipses site seemed old](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html)). I looked into the marketplace and there wasn't a clear choice.  So what I've been doing(which is not the best choice but does what I want) is copy my code to netbeans and run the built in profiling tool that graphically shows me where most of the time is being spent(its just annoying to having to keep copying/pasting code from eclipse to netbeans as I prefer my settings in eclipse over netbeans but cannot profile).

Is there a profiler that I can use in eclipse that is easy and intuitive?

I'm a newbie so sorry in advance if there's a obvious way to do this that I'm missing(or if its built into a common debugger, I haven't learned how to use those yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can start your App in Eclipse and use VisualVM or YourKit or you can use [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/).

Comment: I'm playing around with it and it seems okay, but two problem.  One, if I click run and then have to go another app to run I may miss something depending on how slow I click on the app and second, In visualVM I'm getting extra stuff in my profiling(network traffic on a local app?)

Comment: So make a breakpoint, launch your app, attach VVM and then resume.